# Activity changes when lock screen

Tags: android, android-activity

[SOLVED]

i got a question... When i lock my phone while my app is running, it changes automatically to the main activity (the one which is started at the beginning) when in unlock it.

Anybody knows how to handle that the activity at the moment of locking stays?

Thanks!

Comment: can you elaborate more? have you overridden onResume or onPause on the activity?

Comment: What may be happening also is that it isn't due to the locking/unlocking or the activity but rather an orientation change. Posting relevant activities and manifest may be helpful

Comment: do you have a logcat for what happens on lockscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your activity call finish() in its onPause() method?If so remove it